# Почему ездят НА автобусе?

Tags: предлоги, этимология

Гораздо чаще в речи можно услышать "ехать НА автобусе", нежели "В автобусе". А как вообще правильно? И интересно, предлог "на" пошел еще и тех времен, когда ездили на лошади?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Правильно и так и так.

Когда говорят *на автобусе*, подразумевают средство передвижения (ср. предвигаться *на своих двоих, на лошади, на корабле, на машине, на поезде, на самолёте* и даже *на ракете*). Когда говорят *в автобусе*, подразумевают автобус как место нахождения, комнату (передвигаться *в трюме, в вагоне, в эшелоне, в салоне для некурящих*).

Поэтому *едут **в** битком набитом автобусе*, а совершать манёвры *водитель будет **на** автобусе*.

Answer (score 2):

Все верно: ср.например, английское: to trаvеl оn thе bus - ездить на автобусе.Здесь предлог "на" со словом "автобус" употребляется для обозначения средства передвижения.То же самое  to trаvеl in thе bus - ехать в автобусе.

Comment: Не совсем понял аналогии.

Comment: Все просто.В английском ,как и в русском, эти предлоги совпадают.Ехать на автобусе - to trаvеl оn thе bus (когда подразумевается средство передвижения) , и в автобусе - trаvеl in thе bus(когда подразумевается место нахождения).

Comment: >В английском ,как и в русском, эти предлоги совпадают   
  
С чем совпадают?! И когда **НЕ**  подразумевается средство передвижения??? Коли речь идет об автобусе?
   
На английском, если уж на то пошло, для указания **способа** передвижения вернее всего будет **by bus** (без артикля) - примерный аналог нашего творительного падежа: ехать автобусом. Причем для обоих случаев: и ехать, и ездить.  
**On** годится только для конкретных ситуаций (подробности опускаю).   
  
Место "нахождения" - это "in (inside) the bus". Без "travel".
Travel - это скорее путешествовать, не просто ехать или ездить.

Comment: Средство передвижения не подразумевается, когда человек говорит, где он находится, а не чем передвигается. Например, на вопрос "Ты сейчас где?" ответ будет "В автобусе". А на вопрос "Как ты до Ирины доберешься?" – "На автобусе".

Comment: Совпадают в большинстве случаев,но здесь речь не об этом.Здесь речь о том, что эти предлоги совпадают, когда речь идет о средстве передвижения. To trаvеl оn thе bus - вполне корректная синтагма.Пример взят из оксфордского словаря. Вы правы: основное значение To trаvеl - путешествовать,но этот глагол имеет и значение - ездить.Вот ссылка.http://begin-english.ru/

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос о взаимоотношениях предлогов "в" и "на" в русском языке - одна из любимейших тем всякой филологической тусовки. Но к лошадям он прямого отношения не имеет. 
По отношению к транспортным средствам тут скорее надо рассмотреть другой, не менее  популярный, вопрос - о т.н. глаголах движения и, в частности, ехать и ездить.

Есть такие "парные" глаголы: ехать и ездить, лететь и летать, плыть и плавать и (еще некоторые, к транспортным средствам отношения не имеющие). Глаголы эти интересны сами по себе, но применительно к вопросам темы замечено следующее. За исключением, как Вы верно сказали, лошадей, все такие глаголы требуют НА если глагол используется в значении "направляться" (течь идет о поездке *куда-то*) и предлога В, если значение "находиться", "передвигаться" в транспортном средстве (хотя бы теоретически - зартытом). Сравните: "плыть на лодке" и "находиться в лодке".

Требование это не императивное, к тому же в современном употреблении значение у указанных пар глаголов нередко смешиваются, но тем не менее суть различий использования предлогов НА и В тут проясняется весьма точно. Есть еще одна тонкость. Значение "на чём-то" (на поезде, на самолете) может быть вполне заменена на "чем-то" (поездом, самолётом). По отношению к предлогу В такое обычно исключено, по крайней мере фраза начнет звучать неестественно, типа *Я ехал поездом, когда с меня слетела шляпа*.

Понятно, что частота использования НА в несколько раз (если не на порядок) больше использования В. Просто по числу ситуаций. Этим и объясняется Ваши наблюдения.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, где можно почитать об этой норме, чтобы можно было ссылаться: "Есть еще одна тонкость. Значение "на чём-то" (на поезде, на самолете) может быть вполне заменена на "чем-то" (поездом, самолётом)"- т.е. добираться автобусом, машиной. Спасибо)